# How to copy directory into another preserving specific directory structure?

Tags: linux, file-transfer

I would like to find the command that copy my eclipse options to another workspace:

```
/home/me/myWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/*
```

There is only one directory `org.eclipse.core.runtime` among many to copy into a new workspace preserving the structure `.metadata/.plugins/`. After copy the structure should be:

```
/destination/path/newWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/
```

without manually create `.metadata/.plugins/`

```
[~]$ cd /home/me/myWorkspace/
[myWorkspace]$ cp -Rf .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime -t /destination/path/newWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins
cp: can't create directory '/destination/path/newWorkspace/.metadata/.plugin': No such file or directory
```

It doesn't work, and it could be source of error to write the path `.metadata/.plugins` manually. It certainly a better idea to create a complete script ?

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: You need to create /dest/path/newWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/ if this directory does not exist. You can't copy to a destination that does not exist, otherwise the command you entered should copy the dir to destination exactly as you want.

Comment: I can create the directory with `mkdir -p /destination/pat/newWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins` but it could be source of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
cd /home/me/myWorkspace
cp -Rf --parents .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime /destination/path/newWorkspace
```

Comment: Thanks it does the trick (I've allowed myself to correct the command line about my problem)